# Python: reading a pkcs12 certificate with pyOpenSSL.crypto

Tags: python, cryptography, openssl, digital-certificate, pyopenssl

I have a valid certificate issued by the spanish authority (FNMT) and I want to play with it to learn more about it.
The file has extension .p12

I would like to read the information in it (first and last name) and check if the certificate is valid. Is it possible to do that with pyOpenSSL? I guess I have to use the crypto module in OpenSSL.
Any help or useful link? Trying reading here: http://packages.python.org/pyOpenSSL/openssl-crypto.html but not much information :-(

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It's fairly straight-forward to use. This isn't tested, but should work:

```
# load OpenSSL.crypto
from OpenSSL import crypto

# open it, using password. Supply/read your own from stdin.
p12 = crypto.load_pkcs12(open("/path/to/cert.p12", 'rb').read(), passwd)

# get various properties of said file.
# note these are PyOpenSSL objects, not strings although you
# can convert them to PEM-encoded strings.
p12.get_certificate()     # (signed) certificate object
p12.get_privatekey()      # private key.
p12.get_ca_certificates() # ca chain.
```

For more examples, have a look through the [unit test code of pyopenssl](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@p@y@pyOpenSSL-0.10@test@test_crypto.py/22/OpenSSL.crypto.PKCS12Type/python). Pretty much every way you might want to use the library is there

See also [here](http://nullege.com/codes/search/OpenSSL) or without adverts [here](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/blob/master/tests/test_crypto.py).

Comment: Source link without advertisements: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~exarkun/pyopenssl/trunk/view/head:/OpenSSL/test/test_crypto.py :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't see adverts with Adblock... Edited in.

Comment: This is always printing None. get_certificate, get_privatekey, etc. always returns None. Did it work for anyone ?

Comment: How about python3 solution? I'm having problem with load_pkcs12, because there's no file command now and any manoeuvres I've tried with open() give me lot's of errors. : (  

when trying:  
`p12 = load_pkcs12(open('foo.p12', 'rb').read(), passwd)`
I'm receiving: `OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('asn1 encoding routines', 'ASN1_get_object', 'header too long')]`

Comment: @Stan - are you sure your .p12 file is in the correct format? Try opening it with the openssl tool: `openssl pkcs12 -noout -info -in foo.p12` and see what output you get.

Comment: ```c = p12.get_certificate()     # (signed) certificate object

print(c, p, ca)

print('版本', c.get_version())
print('签名算法', c.get_signature_algorithm())
print('序列号：', c.get_serial_number())
print('证书是否过期：', c.has_expired())
print('在此之前无效：', c.get_notBefore())
print('在此之后无效', c.get_notAfter())



#主题名称
subject = c.get_subject()
print(subject.get_components())

#签发者名称
suer = x509name = c.get_issuer()
print(suer.get_components())

#扩展
print('扩展数：', c.get_extension_count())
print('扩展1：', c.get_extension(0))
```

Answer (score 16):

As pyOpenSSL.crypto.load_pkcs12 is now deprecated, here is the equivalent solution using cryptography, with loading inside a requests Session as a bonus.

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from requests import Session

with open("./cert.p12", "rb") as f:
    (
        private_key,
        certificate,
        additional_certificates,
    ) = serialization.pkcs12.load_key_and_certificates(
        f.read(), CLIENT_CERT_KEY.encode()
    )
# key will be available in user readable temporary file for the time of the
# program run (until key and cert get gc'ed)
key = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
cert = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
key.write(
    private_key.private_bytes(
        encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
        format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
        encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption(),
    )
)
key.flush()
cert.write(
    certificate.public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM),
)
cert.flush()
session = Session()
session.cert = (cert.name, key.name)
```

Comment: This worked, I just had to add a manual import of the method (`import cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.pkcs12`), otherwise I get an attribute error (`AttributeError: module 'cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization' has no attribute 'pkcs12'`)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe is wrong answering to an old Q, but I thought that it may help someone that find this Q after me. This solution work for python 3, and I think is a little bit better. I found it in [the repo of zeep](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/issues/824) and is a class to encapsule the usage.

**Class**

```
import os
from OpenSSL import crypto

class PKCS12Manager():

    def __init__(self, p12file, passphrase):
        self.p12file = p12file
        self.unlock = passphrase
        self.webservices_dir = ''
        self.keyfile = ''
        self.certfile = ''

        # Get filename without extension
        ext = os.path.splitext(p12file)
        self.filebasename = os.path.basename(ext[0])

        self.createPrivateCertStore()
        self.p12topem()

    def getKey(self):
        return self.keyfile

    def getCert(self):
        return self.certfile

    def createPrivateCertStore(self):
        home = os.path.expanduser('~')
        webservices_dir = os.path.join(home, '.webservices')
        if not os.path.exists(webservices_dir):
            os.mkdir(webservices_dir)
        os.chmod(webservices_dir, 0o700)
        self.webservices_dir = webservices_dir

    def p12topem(self):
        p12 = crypto.load_pkcs12(open(self.p12file, 'rb').read(), bytes(self.unlock, 'utf-8'))

        # PEM formatted private key
        key = crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_privatekey())

        self.keyfile = os.path.join(self.webservices_dir, self.filebasename + ".key.pem")
        open(self.keyfile, 'a').close()
        os.chmod(self.keyfile, 0o600)
        with open(self.keyfile, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(key)


        # PEM formatted certificate
        cert = crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_certificate())

        self.certfile = os.path.join(self.webservices_dir, self.filebasename + ".crt.pem")
        open(self.certfile, 'a').close()
        os.chmod(self.certfile, 0o644)
        with open(self.certfile, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(cert)
```

**Usage**

```
from requests import Session
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport

# https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/issues/824
pkcs12 = PKCS12Manager('cert.p12', 'password_for_cert')
session = Session()
session.cert = (pkcs12.getCert(), pkcs12.getKey())

transport = Transport(session=session)
client = Client('url_service', transport=transport)
```