# How to convert PyOpenSSL object to PEM-encoded string?

Tags: pyopenssl

I'm trying to extract the private key and certificate from a PKCS12 file using pyOpenSSL, and am having a hard time figuring out how to convert the data to PEM-encoded strings.  The question below implies that it's possible, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

[Python: reading a pkcs12 certificate with pyOpenSSL.crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345786/python-reading-a-pkcs12-certificate-with-pyopenssl-crypto)

Answer (score 2):

Give a look on the dump_certificate, dump_certificate_request, dump_privatekey methods:
http://pyopenssl.sourceforge.net/pyOpenSSL.html/openssl-crypto.html