# How to check if Certificate from Certificate Log (Not on PC) is revoked using Python?

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have DB with certs from CTL (using 'certstream' utility). Example of one certificate data:

```
{
"all_domains" : [ 
    "benesseresalus.com", 
    "benesseresalus.it", 
    "dimagriresalus.com", 
    "dimagriresalus.it"
],
"as_der" : "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",
"extensions" : {
    "authorityInfoAccess" : "CA Issuers - URI:http://cert.int-x3.letsencrypt.org/\nOCSP - URI:http://ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org\n",
    "authorityKeyIdentifier" : "keyid:A8:4A:6A:63:04:7D:DD:BA:E6:D1:39:B7:A6:45:65:EF:F3:A8:EC:A1\n",
    "basicConstraints" : "CA:FALSE",
    "certificatePolicies" : "Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.44947.1.1.1\n  CPS: http://cps.letsencrypt.org\n  User Notice: is Certificate may only be relied upon by Relying Parties and only in accordance with the Certificate Policy found at https://letsencrypt.org/repository/",
    "ctlPoisonByte" : true,
    "extendedKeyUsage" : "TLS Web server authentication, TLS Web client authentication",
    "keyUsage" : "Digital Signature, Key Encipherment",
    "subjectAltName" : "DNS:www.dimagriresalus.it, DNS:www.dimagriresalus.com, DNS:www.benesseresalus.it, DNS:www.benesseresalus.com, DNS:dimagriresalus.it, DNS:dimagriresalus.com, DNS:benesseresalus.it, DNS:benesseresalus.com",
    "subjectKeyIdentifier" : "A1:89:95:3A:3E:88:ED:EA:5E:3E:8E:71:8F:7D:C4:D4:B0:62:F7:8A"
},
"fingerprint" : "FC:A6:A6:3A:CB:C7:8C:6F:16:84:D3:92:0E:C6:A3:25:D5:91:72:9D",
"not_after" : 1542871339,
"not_before" : 1535095339,
"serial_number" : "381CD50768BA9CBAC7B39C817788EAE33F3",
"subject" : {
    "C" : null,
    "CN" : "benesseresalus.com",
    "L" : null,
    "O" : null,
    "OU" : null,
    "ST" : null,
    "aggregated" : "/CN=benesseresalus.com"
}
}
```

I want to know if this certificate is VALID using code.

I've searched & seen many usages of pyopenssl: https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#revoked-objects

But all of the usage requeires me to have the .pem file. I think I can create the .cert file by opening a new file like this:

```
 ----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----   
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
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

But I still will be lacking the .pem file.

Bottom line: I want to use the json data provided, and know if this certificate is revoked or not. Please tell me what I'm missing.

### Edit

I need python code to do it. I encountered certvalidator - https://github.com/wbond/certvalidator
And running the following code:

```
context = ValidationContext(allow_fetching=True)
validator = CertificateValidator(end_entity_cert, validation_context=context)
```

And I have revocation_mode: soft-fail which means no info as far as I understood.

Comment: Relevant [pyopenssl-convert-certificate-object-to-pem-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796694/pyopenssl-convert-certificate-object-to-pem-file)

Comment: I see it's being signed by my PC and I don't want to modify the cert, just to see if it's revoked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Openssl - How to check if a certificate is revoked or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913440/openssl-how-to-check-if-a-certificate-is-revoked-or-not)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT final:
Thanks to @Steffen Ullrich, the working python code:

```
import os
import subprocess
openssl_location = "\"C:\\Program Files\\OpenSSL-Win64\\bin\\openssl.exe\""`
for element in cursor:
        authorityInfoAccess = element['data']['leaf_cert']['extensions']['authorityInfoAccess']
        ocsp_url, crt_url = [x.strip(" ").lstrip("URI:").rstrip("\n").rstrip("\nCA Issuers") for x in authorityInfoAccess.split("-") if 'URI' in x]

        if 'ocsp' in crt_url:
            ocsp_url, crt_url = crt_url, ocsp_url

        serial_number = authorityInfoAccess = element['data']['leaf_cert']['serial_number']

        shell_convert_cmd = 'curl ' + crt_url + " > issuer.crt"
        os.system(shell_convert_cmd)

        to_pem_cmd = openssl_location + ' x509 -in issuer.crt -inform der -out issuer.pem'
        os.system(to_pem_cmd)

        request_cmd = 'ocsp -issuer issuer.pem -serial 0x' + serial_number + ' -url ' + ocsp_url
        full_cmd = openssl_location + " " + request_cmd
        out = subprocess.check_output(full_cmd, shell=True)
        print (f"program output: {str(out)}")
```