# How to read secret key in p12 file in python

Tags: python

How to read key from p12 file ?

There is simple solution with jceks:

```
def get_jceks_keys(file, passphrase):
    ks = jks.KeyStore.load(file, passphrase)
    return ks.secret_keys
```

but to read data in p12 file ?

I know there was:

```
crypto.load_pkcs12
```

but this solution is deprecated

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345786/python-reading-a-pkcs12-certificate-with-pyopenssl-crypto) this will help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: reading a pkcs12 certificate with pyOpenSSL.crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345786/python-reading-a-pkcs12-certificate-with-pyopenssl-crypto)

Comment: this is 10 years old answered question and as I write in question it is deprecated